# Units of magnetic field to obtain energy in MeV

Tags: energy, magnetic-fields, units, spectroscopy

Is it possible to use a unit of magnetic field to obtain the value of kinetic energy in units of MeV? For context, I'm handling beta spectroscopy data and the equation is:

$ K = \sqrt{ (eBrc)^2 + m_e^{2}c^{4} } - m_{e}c^2 $

Also, r is a length quantity. I am aware that length can be represented as units of $hc/eV$ but haven't found a relevant unit conversion for B yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1T= 1\frac{Vs}{m^2}$ corresponds to $\frac{299.792}{ce}\frac{MeV}{m}$ ($c$ stands for speed of light and $e$ for the elementary charge) as it can be easy checked by reducing the fraction with $c=0.299792\cdot 10^9\frac{m}{s}$ and $e$ ($\frac{MeV}{e}=MV)$.

Comment: Made my life a lot easier that I don't have to reduce the length into natural units. Thanks a ton!

Comment: there has been a typo in the value of the speed of light, now it is correct.